# error in redirection in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, mongoid

i'm new to ruby on rails . i have a member and every member has many health records and i made a button for the member to add a new health record in HealthyGrocery/app/views/members/hub.html.erb where the hub is the home page
`<%= button_to "new health record", redirect_to= 'http://localhost:3000/health_record/new', :method => "get" %>`
by this button i want to redirect to this link "localhost:3000/health_record/new" which is in HealthyGrocery/app/views/health_record/new.html.erb
and when i run the server and press the button to make a new health record it gives me this error[screenshot of the error](http://postimg.org/image/d73lv7huh/)

Answer (score 0):

```
redirect_to PATH
```

The command you used inside of a button is completely out of context. You should only use this inside controllers, as a means of redirecting where the flow will go next based on the result of an operation.

Say, after successfully posting a post on a forum, if it was a success, you'd redirect the user to his new topic. If it failed, you'd redirect the user to the post form once again so he could correct it.

What you wanted to do, was use an automatic path_helper:

```
new_health_record_path
```

You'd also use a link_to instead of a button_to, and there would be no need to specify the HTTP method.

End result:

```
link_to('new health record', new_health_record_path)
```